# Methods not applicable for the implementation of an interface: throw Exception or ignore silently?

Tags: java

I'm currently implementing a rather large interface and some of its methods are not applicable to the implementation.

Should I do something akin to:

```
/**
 * @throws UnsupportedOperationException always. This method is not applicable.
 */
public void fooMethod() {
  throw new UnsupportedOperationException("This method is not applicable for this implementation.");
}
```

or just silently ignore it, doing nothing:

```
public void fooMethod() {
}
```

The former way would alert a user of the class that it doesn't do a portion of what the interface provides, but might perhaps clash with legacy code where the class is used as a drop-in replacement (which it isn't, though).

Is there a general rule regarding this?

Comment: I think this stack-exchange [proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/11464/code-review?referrer=aWNm_PdciyFqjFW8CUacGw2 "code review") might be of interest to you. If it is show your support and help get it to beta. Then you can tell other people why their code sucks ass and what they can do to make it suck less ;)

Comment: @Victor: There's pertty much only one language where I'd be capable of doing that, but nearly one no one uses `cmd` ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that simply depends on the contract defined by the method.

If for example "remove" is not supported by your "List" implementation, you should throw an exception to indicate that this behavior is missing because the client relies on an expected result.

If the  feature is optional in the sense that the **contract** says for example  "this method should inform the user about an ongoing activity" you're free to make a dummy implementation.

Comment: +1 to contract.  Sometimes it is valid to have an empty implementation, sometimes an exception must be thrown.

Answer (score 5):

Throw an `UnsupportedOperationException`, definitely. I can't see any benefit in failing silently, unless the method is meant to be a "hint" sort of method.

If you can refactor your interface and split it up a bit, that would probably be cleaner - but I understand that with a legacy codebase this may not be feasible.

Comment: Not my interface, sadly. Just an implementation of `RowSet` that doesn't do anything with the command, username or password properties since it operates on a flat file.

Comment: @Joey: Right. So I guess the question is whether it's *reasonable* for something to specify the username/password in a "dumb" fashion, and for you to ignore it - or whether that shows that the client is doing something definitely wrong.

Answer (score 0):

UnsupportedOperationException is better. Otherwise client code cannot distinguish the method is availble or not.